# How do I increment date and time?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, winforms

I want to display the current date and time in my application, I want to use the time from a server to prevent users from changing the system clock in their own machines. My current setup is a timer querying the time on the server every second. I haven't implemented this, i'm worried about performance since there will be about 50 clients. How big is the performance issue if there's 50 clients querying the server time every second? on a sql server? on an oracle database?

```
If timecon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then timecon.Open()
timecmd = New SqlCommand("Select CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 114)", timecon)
lblServerTime.Text = timecmd.ExecuteScalar
```

I was thinking I could query the server time on form load then just increment that every second. Have a timer increment the second, minute, hour, day, month, year. How can I do this?

Or if possible how can I sync the machine datetime with the server datetime on form load? like query the server datetime and use that to change the client machine datetime.

Comment: Why do you need to resync every second?  Are you worried a second is longer (or shorter) on the client vs the server?  The first time you query, you could get the difference and use that to display an adjusted time.  *Maybe* requery ever 5 mins or so to update the difference, nit I would not expect it to change much if at all

Comment: @Plutonix the system will be time sensitive, the client must know the exact time.

Comment: How will using a Timer on the client get you the exact server time?

Comment: `I was thinking I could query the server time on form load then just increment that every second. `  I am suggesting it is simpler to save a TimeSpan of the difference between the 2 times and just adjust the client time for use/display

Comment: Before we can answer this you need to specify how far out the local time may drift from server time. Re-syncing every second sounds like it might be unnecessarily stringent. How about once every minute? Or immediatley before the time-critical operation, wahtever it is?

Comment: @peterG re-syncing every 5 minutes would be fine.

Comment: then 50 clients querying once every 5 mins  - 10 every minute - sounds like it's not a big performance issue - far as we can tell (- vague terms in the question, vague terms in the answer ;-)  )

Comment: I understand the desire to display the server time, but is this value being used for some type of timestamp.  If so, why not use the SQL GETDATE() function in the command text versus supplying a value?

Comment: Google for `time synchronization software` - turns up about 5.4 million results. This is general purpose software and while you can spend time hand-rolling your own in the end it'll be more trouble than it's worth. I suggest that you buy something that's designed to do what you're trying to do. Best of luck.

Comment: @TnTinMn I use the getdate() function in my query, I just want to display the time so the user knows what time will be inserted to the database before they even do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is a good one, if you query the time in the load and then set the timer to 1000 or one second, all you would need to do is set variables that reset after hitting sixty and add one to the next. ex: second counter hits sixty, resets, adds one to the minute etc... the first time you should have it check the server after a few minutes to make sure its not lagging behind any.